# Cant' select Edit button in facebook with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

I want to click on this button my earlier try with XPATH was successful, but  now I can't click it with XPATH.
XPATH: `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]`

I have a question. Which path should I chose? Parent element path, here it is `div` or any element regarding this button is okay

`webdriverwait` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\meetg\PycharmProjects\python\FB_Bot\fb_bot.py", line 54, in <module>
    edit_post(browser, post_link, fb_elem_XPATH)
  File "c:\Users\meetg\PycharmProjects\python\FB_Bot\bot_functions.py", line 45, in edit_post
    edit_post = WebDriverWait(browser, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, fb_elem_XPATH['edit-post-btn'])))
  File "C:\Users\meetg\PycharmProjects\python\FB_Bot\fbvenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:181:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:393:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:299:16
```

Comment: this xpath is too complex  fb changes ui very ofter try using your own xpath

Comment: What do you mean by my own XPATH?

Comment: No. Absolute xpath is a strict no as far as I am concerned. Take a relative xpath like this one `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'Hide post']").click()`
FB is a react app, which has a lot of async and the use of Virtual DOM makes it a bit difficult than the conventional web apps. Take care to introduce `webdriverwait` wherever required, and if requrired `sleep` too.

Comment: @AnandGautam Everytime I use `webdriverwait` I get the error as edited in my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to base element locators on element text, but Facebook site uses multiple changing class names with no any fixed element attributes, so in this specific case I would advice to use the following XPath locator:

```
"//span[text()='Edit post']"
```

Comment: I like to take your suggestions about finding XPath for the facebook

Comment: Does all the attributes work in relative XPATH like, `div[@attribute="xyz"]` where `attribute` == `value`, `aria-label`, `data-sigil`, etc?

Comment: Yes, but there are some special attributes like text. In this case it will look like `//div[text()="OK"]`